# Hot tow how the usage of a variable or method in Visual Studio 2012 (C Sharp)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

The eclipse IDE has the wonderful feature to show where a variable or method is used. Hotkey: `CTRL + SHIFT + g`.

Is there something equivalent in Visual Studio 2012 (C Sharp)?

Comment: [Shift+F12, or right-click Find All References.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/da5kh0wa.aspx)

Comment: Check out resharper: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Finding_Usages.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SHIFT + F12` will find all references with default visual studio configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the object you want to inspect, then select `Find all references`.

In my case, it's `CTRL + K, then R`